# Can I view previous changes made to a php file in cPanel?

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I was editing my website yesterday, and realized today that I accidentally deleted a string of code that I need. I don't remember the specifics of the code, so I'm wondering if it is possible to view a previous version of all coding of the page to recover the code I deleted?

Some useful info - I am using a cPanel login, hosting with GoDaddy and website is run though WordPress. The page in question is just the header.php file for a theme I have installed.

Comment: you have backps? why dont you have backups? I bet you have backups NOW

Comment: ermmm @nogad, unfortunately don't think I've ever done a backup. Very bad, I know.

Comment: well you wont be doing that again. if its a core wordpress file, you can just download a new copy

Comment: ...And that's why you never edit production code that's live.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you don't have a backup of the file (either locally or on the server), then you won't be able to recover the code.

However, I suggest you to use Version Control, such as Subversion or Git Hub. This is something you can install on your own computer.

With those, you have all your code/files on your computer, edit them as you need, and then when you're done with your changes, you do a "Commit".

The next time you make changes, you can see the differences between your new changes and the code that is live.
You can also see a log of all the previous changes, which is very helpful when you wonder who made a change or what was the reason for a given change, in case you don't remember. :)